# Why haven't I got my badge 'Enlightened'?

Tags: support, badges

I have first answered one question and my answer got accepted, but why haven't I got the 'Enlightened' Badge yet?

Comment: Because it also requires having a score of 10...

Comment: -3 downvotes, that means that asking question is not encouraged??? put downvote to get score??? too easy but not kind!!!

Comment: That means: this question isn't useful or lacks research. The downvotes thought either of those applies on your question.

Comment: ha ha ha, looks many persons are waiting for puting downvote

Answer (score 9):

The full description of the Enlightened badge is:

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more.

You have no answers with a score of 10. When (if) that answer gets a score of 10 (which is number of upvotes - number of downvotes), you will be eligible to the badge.

Additionally, badges are **not** awarded immediately - they are awarded in a batch job (different badges have different schedules).

Comment: so please explain a score of 10, is 10+ reputations?

Comment: No. Score == upvotes - downvotes. So, if you have 10 upvotes and 0 downvotes on the answer, that's a score of 10. If you have 11 upvotes and 2 downvotes, that's a score of 9.

Comment: Ok see! you have my score.